# Redirect ALL requests under a domain to static page

Tags: apache, configuration, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect ALL requests for mydomain.com whether they are something like:

- http://www.mydomain.com
- http://mydomain.com
- http://mydomain.com/photos
- http://mydomain.com/index.php?id=672

to be redirected to

- http://mydomain.com/index.html

As long as it has mydomain.com in it, they should see this page - its a we'll be back soon message.

Should I do it in .htaccess or conf? How?

Comment: Why is this off topic? Too bad I can't cast any reopening votes yet.

Comment: Now that I can (hooray), bump.

Comment: @bjb568 yea who knows; obviously there are multiple tags specifically for this sort of question on SO. i can understand folks may have a preference to have this on serverfault but calling this out of scope is rather abusive of authority and common sense. \o/

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I actually ended up finding the answer on ServerFault:

https://serverfault.com/questions/32513/url-redirect-to-another-page-on-the-same-site

"This example will 302 redirect all URLs to "/underconstruction.html":

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/underconstruction.html
RewriteRule ^ /underconstruction.html [R=302]
```

(which translates as "If URI is not /underconstruction.html, redirect to /underconstruction.html")" - Tommeh

Comment: If this does not work at first, try changing the apache.conf (on linux: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf ) setting `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` inside the `<Directory "/var/www/html">` configuration.  Then restart apache ( on linux: /etc/init.d/httpd restart )

Comment: This breaks images or css files etc. as all assets are being repointed to the html file.